# Missing \title{} in R documentation files generated with devtools+roxygen2

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, r-s4, roxygen2

I'm writing an R package using devtools and roxygen2 to do the documentation. The documentation is working fine for all but two of my R files. For those two, the documentation file (.Rd) for first function is generated without a \title{} line. For example, this is how the top of my normal rd files look:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/general.R
\name{rmsd}
\alias{rmsd}
\title{Calculates the Root Mean Squared Deviation/Error}
\usage{...`
```

Which is generated by the code block:

```
#' Calculates the Root Mean Squared Deviation/Error
#'
#' This function calculates the root mean squared error/deviation (RMSD/E)
#'     between two vectors of numbers.
#'
#' @param x numeric, the first vector
#' @param y numeric, the second vector 
#' @param na.rm logical, should NAs be removed from the vectors?
#' @return This function returns the RMSD of the two vectors.
#' @examples
#' a <- rnorm(10)
#' b <- rnorm(10)
#' rmsd(a,b)
#' @export
rmsd <- function(...
```

The abnormal ones look like this:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/constructors.R
\name{parameterlist}
\alias{parameterlist}
\usage{...
```

and are generated by this code block:

```
#' @include plantmethodsbasic.R thermal.R general.R  

#This script has constructor functions for both ParameterList and Plant classes

#' Creates ParameterList object
#'
#' This function creates an object of the class ParameterList. Plant objects
#'     require objects of the class ParameterList for their parameters slot.
#'
#' @param ct A list, data.frame, or matrix of cardinal temperatures. In the
#'     case of a data.frame or matrix, each row should contain the cardinal
#'     temperatures for a given stage of the model. If ct is a list, each
#'     element of the list should be a vector of cardinal temperatures for a
#'     given stage of the model.
#' @param length A vector of model lengths
#' @return An object of the class ParameterList.
#' @export
parameterlist <- function(...
```

If I create (and document) a dummy function at the top of these files and use the devtools::document() command, that function becomes the one without the title. If I then delete the dummy function from the file and redocument the package, the \title{} argument is removed from my original function. If anyone has any ideas as to what is going on I would be much appreciative. I could write the rest of the documentation files myself but I would prefer not to.

Oh this is an S4 package if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you also show at least the tops of the roxygen comment blocks for those functions?